# eloquence voices are speaking extra bs

Tags: speech-to-text, speech-synthesis, avspeechsynthesizer, iphone-web-app

Here below is the code snippet I used to speak some text

```js
  const synth = window.speechSynthesis;
  const utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(text);
  utterance.voice = selectedVoice;
  synth.speak(utterance);
```

It works perfectly on Mac Chrome.
But when I try it on IOS Chrome, it behaves differently.

Here is a list of available voice for language `en-GB` on IOS Chrome.

For voices with `compact` in the voiceURI, they works fine. They just speak content in `text`.
For voices with `eloquence` in the voiceURI, they are speaking extra information, more than the parameter `text` I gave.
It speaks `'speak. Voice name equals "com apple eloquence en-GB Grandma"'`;  content in `text`; `'Voice. speak.'`

```
SpeechSynthesisVoice {voiceURI: "com.apple.eloquence.en-GB.Rocko", name: "Rocko", lang: "en-GB", localService: true, default: true}
1 SpeechSynthesisVoice {voiceURI: "com.apple.eloquence.en-GB.Shelley", name: "Shelley", lang: "en-GB", localService: true, default: true}
2 SpeechSynthesisVoice {voiceURI: "com.apple.voice.compact.en-GB.Daniel", name: "Daniel", lang: "en-GB", localService: true, default: true}
3 SpeechSynthesisVoice {voiceURI: "com.apple.eloquence.en-GB.Grandma", name: "Grandma", lang: "en-GB", localService: true, default: true}
4 SpeechSynthesisVoice {voiceURI: "com.apple.eloquence.en-GB.Grandpa", name: "Grandpa", lang: "en-GB", localService: true, default: true}
5 SpeechSynthesisVoice {voiceURI: "com.apple.eloquence.en-GB.Flo", name: "Flo", lang: "en-GB", localService: true, default: true}
6 SpeechSynthesisVoice {voiceURI: "com.apple.eloquence.en-GB.Eddy", name: "Eddy", lang: "en-GB", localService: true, default: true}
7 SpeechSynthesisVoice {voiceURI: "com.apple.eloquence.en-GB.Reed", name: "Reed", lang: "en-GB", localService: true, default: true}
8 SpeechSynthesisVoice {voiceURI: "com.apple.eloquence.en-GB.Sandy", name: "Sandy", lang: "en-GB", localService: true, default: true}
9 SpeechSynthesisVoice {voiceURI: "com.apple.voice.super-compact.en-GB.Daniel", name: "Daniel", lang: "en-GB", localService: true, default: true}
```

I am wondering why there are differences in content for different voices.